# How to add user input text into the const list?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In MUI autocomplete component, I wish when user input some text, our system could save it into the list, and load the list when user click it on next time.

```
<Autocomplete
id="free-solo-demo"
freeSolo
options={top100Films.map((option) => option.title)}
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="freeSolo" />}
      />
```

Now, the free solo is open. User could input any text they want. How could we add those into the list?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could do it:

Whenever the user types something in, display the matches as well as what the user types.

If the user clicks on the option they type, or presses the enter key, and the options does not contain what the user typed, add it to the list of options, and set it to be selected.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/mystifying-bhaskara-1yr1gs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is a minimal codesandbox that accomplishes this, or, here is a more complete example that is able to handle multiple selection

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material";

function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<string[]>([
    "option 1",
    "option 2",
    "option 3",
    "option 4",
    "option 5",
  ]);

  return (
    <TokenizingAutocomplete
      autocompleteProps={{
        id: "tokenizing-demo",
        //multiple: true,
      }}
      options={options}
      addOption={(option) => {
        setOptions(options.concat(option));
      }}
    />
  );
}

interface TokenizingAutocompleteProps {
  options: string[];
  addOption: (option: string) => void;
  autocompleteProps?: any;
}

function TokenizingAutocomplete(props: TokenizingAutocompleteProps) {
  const { options, addOption, autocompleteProps } = props;
  const [currentText, setCurrentText] = useState<string>("");

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...autocompleteProps}
      // by default show the options and whatever the user has typed, if what they have typed is not in the list of options
      options={
        options.includes(currentText) ? options : options.concat(currentText)
      }
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Options"
          // if the user types something that is not in the list of options add it to the list of options
          onChange={(e) => {
            setCurrentText(e.target.value);
          }}
          // if the user presses enter and what they have typed is not in the list of options add it to the list of options
          onKeyDown={(e) => {
            if (e.key === "Enter" && !options.includes(currentText)) {
              addOption(currentText);
            }
          }}
        />
      )}
      // if the user selects the option, permanantly add it to the list of options. do not add it if it is already in the list of options, or selection type is multiple
      onChange={(e, value: string) => {
        if (value && !options.includes(value) && !autocompleteProps?.multiple) {
          addOption(value);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get some idea with the [creatable autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#creatable) example.

1. `filterOptions`: append the user-typed option item.
2. `getOptionLabel`: adds a prefix to the new item.
3. switch inside `onChange` to set `value` with the new item.

```js
<Autocomplete
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        if (typeof newValue === 'string') {
          setValue({
            title: newValue,
          });
        } else if (newValue && newValue.inputValue) {
          // Create a new value from the user input
          setValue({
            title: newValue.inputValue,
          });
        } else {
          setValue(newValue);
        }
      }}
      filterOptions={(options, params) => {
        const filtered = filter(options, params);

        const { inputValue } = params;
        // Suggest the creation of a new value
        const isExisting = options.some((option) => inputValue === option.title);
        if (inputValue !== '' && !isExisting) {
          filtered.push({
            inputValue,
            title: `Add "${inputValue}"`,
          });
        }

        return filtered;
      }}
      selectOnFocus
      clearOnBlur
      handleHomeEndKeys
      id="free-solo-with-text-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => {
        // Value selected with enter, right from the input
        if (typeof option === 'string') {
          return option;
        }
        // Add "xxx" option created dynamically
        if (option.inputValue) {
          return option.inputValue;
        }
        // Regular option
        return option.title;
      }}
      renderOption={(props, option) => <li {...props}>{option.title}</li>}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      freeSolo
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Free solo with text demo" />
      )}
    />
```